# Configure curly braces with StyleCop

Tags: stylecop

Is it possible to get StyleCop to say that this is the correct way to use curly braces?

```
if (request.Query == string.Empty) {
    return SearchResponse.Empty;
}
```

But not this

```
if (request.Query == string.Empty)
    return SearchResponse.Empty;
```

Or this:

```
if (request.Query == string.Empty)
{
    return SearchResponse.Empty;
}
```

I also want this behavior for if, else, else if, while, foreach and for. But not for class declarations or method declarations.

Comment: -1 You are trying to subvert the entire purpose of stylecop. Stylecop defines a set of consistent standards that you adopt. If you want a set of inconsistent rules, then you need a woolly tool like resharper.

Comment: I think you are wrong. I want some StyleCop rules, and not others. And I want consistency and enforcement with the rules I do choose.

Comment: I agree with @Binary255, although I prefer the behavior of StyleCop.

Comment: @Philip Smith - StyleCop is a rules engine, whilst it comes with a number of rules which Microsoft feel are the best it is still fully configurable and extensible so that you can define the rules how you feel is best, even if they are evil and try to make C# look like Java :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it does that out of the box; however, StyleCop ships with an SDK that includes instructions on how to author custom rules. Although it would be most helpful if someone has already created a custom rule accomplishing what you describe, you may find that you must roll your own.

I was going to add a link to the SDK docs, but the .CHM appeared to be broken at the time. You may need to get the whole project from http://stylecop.codeplex.com to read up on details.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I`ll look into it when I have some spare time. I hope it´s an easy SDK so that I can accomplish it without too much effort. :-)